# Showing $a \setminus (a \setminus b) = a \cap b$ using only set notation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

I need to prove that $a \setminus (a \setminus b) = a \cap b$ only through set notations.

I have reached the fact that 
$a \setminus (a \setminus b)$ = {x | x $\in$ A $\land$ x $\notin$ (A $\setminus$ B}

Which I then simplify using the De Morgan' formula to
{x | x $\in$ A $\land$ (x $\notin$ A $\lor$ x $\in$ B)}.

It is evident that this is the same as A $\cap$ B (by constructing diagrams and truth tables). But how do I get this expression to {x | x $\in$ A $\land$ x $\in$ B}? Please help!

Comment: Use `$\{ X\}$` for $\{ X\}$.

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent are:

- $x\in A\wedge(x\notin A\vee x\in B)$
- $(x\in A\wedge x\notin A)\vee(x\in A\wedge x\in B)$
- $x\in A\wedge x\in B$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please explain how do I get from line 1 to line 2?

Comment: By applying distributivity of $\wedge $ wrt $\vee $. Not familiar with that yet? A Boolean algebra is distributive lattice.

Comment: Completely missed that! Understood. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

a - (a - b) = a - (a $\cap$ b$^c$) =
a - (a$^c$ $\cup$ b)$^c$ = a $\cap$ (a$^c$ $\cup$ b)
= (a $\cap$ a$^c$) $\cup$ (a $\cap$ b) = a $\cap$ b